# Excel Round number up to a specific number given a range

Tags: microsoft-excel

I have a set of definite number, like this:

```
50
100
200
500
1000
```

I would like to round a number up to nearest number like this:

```
20 => 50
55 => 100
433 => 500
```

Are there any specific function that i could use?

Comment: Please explain your rounding in more detail. Is there a column of rounding boundaries? Are they sorted? Is a number on one of the boundaries unchanged, or rounded up to the next?

Answer (score 7):

You can use the `INDEX` and `MATCH` functions to do your rounding.

Put the numbers you want to round to in **descending** order in one column (I'm going to assume they are in cells A1:A5). Put the number that you want to be rounded in another cell (I'm going to assume it is in B1).

In another cell, enter the formula

```
=INDEX($A$1:$A$5,MATCH(B1,$A$1:$A$5,-1))
```

This will return the number from B1 rounded up to the next highest number from the range A1:A5.

[image]

The way this works is that `MATCH` finds the position in the range A1:A5 of the lowest number that is greater than or equal to the number in B1. `INDEX` returns the value from the range A1:A5 at the podition returned by `MATCH`.

Note that numbers higher than 1000 (the highest number in the range) will return #N/A. If you want to avoid having 0 round up to 50, you can enter 0 in cell A6 and change the ranges in the formula to $A$1:$A$6 (values of zero or less will then round to zero).

Answer (score 3):

Use:

```
=INDEX({50,100,200,500,1000},MATCH(A1,{0,51,101,201,501}))
```

[image]

Comment: I found this to be the most elegant solution - thanks!
A short explanation for others, the idea is to create two arrays (in { }): the first containing the array of numbers to be rounded to; the second containing the limits or range for rounding.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming your value is in A1

```
=IF(A1<=50,50,IF(A1<=100,100,IF(A1<=200,200,IF(A1<=500,500,IF(A1<=1000,1000,A1)))))
```

(with the above formula anything over 1000 won't get rounded)

Comment: yea, I wrote exactly that, but it would be nicer to have a smarter functions

Comment: If you want to round up to a regular interval (say every 50) you could use: `=ROUNDUP(A1/50,0)*50`, but for arbitrary values (like the ones you have), it is hard to have something elegant.

Answer (score 1):

`10    > round up to the nearest whole number
100    > round up to the nearest multiple of 5
1000   > round up to the nearest multiple of 10
10000  > round up to multiple of 50
50000  > round up to multiple of 100
100000 > round up to multiple of 1000
100000 < round up to multiple of 10000`

Formula:

```
 =IF(I6<=10,MROUND(I6,1),IF(I6<=100,MROUND(I6,5),IF(I6<=1000,MROUND(I6,10),IF(I6<=10000,MROUND(I6,50),IF(I6<=50000,MROUND(I6,100),IF(100000>I6,MROUND(I6,1000),IF(100000<=I6,MROUND(I6,10000))))
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have a reasonably small range, you can use Excel's LOOKUP() function.

```
=LOOKUP(A1, {20,55,433}, {50,100,500})
```

**Note:** This approach is only useful if you know the values of all the numbers to be rounded up in advance.  If you need to round up an arbitrary number whose value is not known, then you should use one of the other solutions.